# Using .closest on an img to fade out the image

Tags: jquery, closest

I'm trying to use `.closest` to `fadeOut` an image. The image to be faded has a class of `.icon`, there are multiple `.icons` on the page so I wanted to use `this` and `.closest` to target the `.icon` within the same div as the clicked element.

My JS Fiddle shows the functionality. Click the smaller square and the text fades in. https://jsfiddle.net/x9sxcLr9/

However the icon/large square should also fade out as the text fades in. This is the code for that functionality:

```
$(this).closest("img.icon").fadeOut( "fast", function() {});
```

The HTML set up uses `.cross` as the event handler, so it should find the correct `.icon` close by (in the same div) but it doesn't seem to find it...

```
<div class="">
            <img class="icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
            <img class="cross" src="http://placehold.it/35x35" />
            ...
</div>

$( ".cross" ).click(function() { ... }
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `closest()` is looking for ancestor (including element itself), not sibling  `$(this).siblings("img.icon").fadeOut( "fast", function() {});` FYI, the DOC for jQuery is great ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `siblings` instead of `closest`. `Closest` will look for the ancestor having the given class. Since the element is the sibling of the clicked element use `siblings`.

```
$(".cross").click(function() {
    var status = $(this).parent().attr("class")

    if (status == 'active') {
        $(this).parent(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $(this).parent(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).siblings("img.icon").fadeOut("fast", function() {});
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/x9sxcLr9/1/

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/), which will match the elements before the clicked:

```
$(this).prev("img.icon").fadeOut( "fast", function() {});
```

[Your fiddle, updated.](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/x9sxcLr9/2/)

Comment: @A.Wolff Yeah, but I'd argue "sort of". I mean, saying that would be too specific and generic at the same time. The element may have thousands of siblings. The element may have other icons that are siblings, but shouldn't fade out, and so on. I mean: maintainability is not something inherent to `.prev()` or `.siblings()` - it depends on the use case.